Ubuntu 22/04 xrdp worked briefly then stopped
Current state
updated all packages.
Works after a reboot, then stops.
Can ssh fine.
ufw allows 3389
$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " | grep ":3389"
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN

xrdp status
$
sudo systemctl status xrdp
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-06-10 01:10:30 BST; 3min 50s ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
    Process: 1131057 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1131065 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1131066 (xrdp)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8764)
     Memory: 864.0K
        CPU: 22ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
             └─1131066 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Jun 10 01:10:29 WOWE systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Jun 10 01:10:29 WOWE xrdp[1131065]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Jun 10 01:10:29 WOWE xrdp[1131065]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Jun 10 01:10:29 WOWE xrdp[1131065]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
Jun 10 01:10:29 WOWE systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after star>
Jun 10 01:10:30 WOWE systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.
Jun 10 01:10:31 WOWE xrdp[1131066]: [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 1131066
Jun 10 01:10:31 WOWE xrdp[1131066]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Jun 10 01:10:31 WOWE xrdp[1131066]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Jun 10 01:10:31 WOWE xrdp[1131066]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done

I think this is right
What else should I check to make this work?
